# List<string>.replace issue

Tags: c#

I made a tool and it worked fine, for some reason now I got a problem:

Good

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Bad

```
line1 line2 line3
```

Before it worked just like the [Good example] and now it works like the [bad example]

Code:

```
string[] temp = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Normal/DorkType.txt");
        foreach (string s in temp)
            DorkType.Add(s);
        // Load the Keywords
        string[] temp1 = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Normal/Keywords.txt");
        foreach (string s in temp)
            Keywords.Add(s);
        // Load the Domains
        string[] temp2 = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Normal/Domains.txt");
        foreach (string s in temp)
            Domains.Add(s);
        // Load the PageType
        string[] temp3 = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Normal/PageType.txt");
        foreach (string s in temp)
            PageType.Add(s);
        // Load the PageFormat
        string[] temp4 = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Normal/PageFormat.txt");
        foreach (string s in temp)
            PageFormat.Add(s);
        // Load the SearchFunctions
        string[] temp5 = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Normal/SearchFunction.txt");
        foreach (string s in temp)
            SearchFunction.Add(s);
        // Load the Type
        string[] temp6 = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + $"/HQmethods/Preset/Preset{Preset}.txt");
        foreach (string s in temp)
            Type.Add(s);
        // Load the Keyword
        string[] temp7 = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/HQmethods/Keyword.txt");
        foreach (string s in temp)
            Keyword.Add(s);
        // Load the 2nd Keyword
        string[] temp8 = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/HQmethods/Keyword2.txt");
        foreach (string s in temp)
            Keyword2.Add(s);

if (PageFormatType == "None" || PageFormatType == "none")
{
    // if the user choose the None mode
    // Replace 'KW' with the user Keywords
    NewDorks.Add(DorkType[counter]
        .Replace("KW", Keywords[rnd.Next(0, Keywords.Count)])
        .Replace("PT", PageType[rnd.Next(0, PageType.Count)])
        .Replace("PF", PageFormat[rnd.Next(0, PageFormat.Count)])
        .Replace("DE", Domains[rnd.Next(0, Domains.Count)])
        .Replace("SF", SearchFunction[rnd.Next(0, SearchFunction.Count)]));

    counter++;
}

public static void SaveDorks()
{
    using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + 
        "/Finished.txt"))
    {
        foreach (string s in NewDorks)
            write.WriteLine(s);
        write.Close();
    }
}
```

This piece of code is in a different class, I called it in the Main class

NewDorks --> `List<string>`

DorkType --> `List<string>`

Let's say I have a text file with:

```
1
2
3
```

instead of Adding it to NewDorks and the output will look like this

```
1
2
3
```

The output is like this:

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: where did you write into the file?

Comment: The problem is not in the Save method, the problem is in the NewDorks.add();

Comment: `write.WriteLine(s + Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: @Alex when stepping through the debugger in `SaveDorks()` how many items are in your `NewDorks` List?

Comment: @Darren I checked it and for some reason NewDorks just few lines in the same place, for example:
instead of:
1
new line
2
new line
3

it just add 1 2 3

Comment: @Chris is it allowed to send a picture?

Comment: Yes, you can embed images in your post. I only ask because it could be simply a matter of you having only one item in your list, but all the `lines` being appended to one item.

Comment: yes, lines appended to one item

Comment: You said, *"Before it worked just like the [Good example] and now it works like the [bad example]"*. Can you answer: before ***what***?

Comment: How are you viewing the file? One thought is web browsers treat all white space as a single space, so opening this as if it were an html document would show the bad output, even if the file had good newline characters.

Comment: I did the same thing, but everything was in 1 class, now I moved it to a different class

Comment: Also, you can do a case-insensitive comparison using: `if (PageFormatType.Equals("none", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: Thank you, but you can see that we cannot copy/paste that example since we don't have those files, but it's a good start. Instead it would be helpful if you did something like: `List<string> DorkType = new List<string>
{
    "Random keyword: KW",
    "Random page type: PT",
    "Random page format: PF"
};
List<string> Keywords = new List<string> {"keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3"};
List<string> PageType = new List<string> {"pageType1", "pageType2", "pageType3"};`

Comment: `List<string> PageFormat = new List<string> {"pageFormat1", "pageFormat2", "pageFormat3"};
List<string> Domains = new List<string> {"domain1", "domain2", "domain3"};
List<string> SearchFunction = new List<string> {"searchFunction1", "searchFunction2", "searchFunction3"};`

Comment: `for (int counter = 0; counter < DorkType.Count; counter++)
{
    NewDorks.Add(DorkType[counter]
        .Replace("KW", Keywords[rnd.Next(0, Keywords.Count)])
        .Replace("PT", PageType[rnd.Next(0, PageType.Count)])
        .Replace("PF", PageFormat[rnd.Next(0, PageFormat.Count)])
        .Replace("DE", Domains[rnd.Next(0, Domains.Count)])
        .Replace("SF", SearchFunction[rnd.Next(0, SearchFunction.Count)]));
}` Would this sample code reproduce your issue?

Comment: Did you notice that all of your `foreach` loops are looping over the same array `temp`? You never use any of your `temp1`, `temp2`, etc arrays

Comment: yeah, I just noticed it :) thank you